# Dixmier trace, Wodzicki residue and topological index

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, kt.k-theory-and-homology, index-theory

There are a well-known facts about Dixmier trace and Wodzicki residue. Let $P$ be an elliptic pseudodifferential operator of degree $−n$ on a compact Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$, than its Dixmier trace is related to the Wodzicki residue by the formula:
$$
\operatorname{Tr}^{+} P=\frac{1}{n(2 \pi)^{n}} \operatorname{Res} P
$$
Also, for an arbitrary smooth function $a \in C^{\infty}(M)$ the following equality
$$
\int_{M} a(x)\left|\nu_{g}\right|=\frac{n(2 \pi)^{n}}{\Omega_{n}} \operatorname{Tr}^{+}\left(a \Delta_{g}^{-n / 2}\right)
$$
holds. Is it possible to associate Wodzicki residue and topological index of the operator $a \Delta_{g}^{-n / 2}$? For example, can a something like $\operatorname{Tr}^{+}\left(a \Delta_{g}^{-n / 2}\right) \in H^*_{b, dR}(M)$ take place? Where $H^*_{b, dR}(M)$ can be understood as bounded John Roe's cohomology classes.